# How Can I Attach an Email With Laravel Default Reset Password Link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

How can I attach an email along with the token?

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
    }

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password'),
            url(config('http://mywebsite.local/') . 
                route('password.reset', $this->token, false)));
}
```

`

Comment: what do you mean by "attaching" ?

Comment: my url was look like this  http://mywebsite/password/reset/5c7e0b4e40303976277bd64896a0ce9fe9939719a8bb9c21bf724c9b4c2daae6                                                                   and i want to add email with this just like this http://mywebsite/password/reset/mnmruzaik@gmail.com/5c7e0b4e40303976277bd64896a0ce9fe9939719a8bb9c21bf724c9b4c2daae6

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you create a table called "password_reset" that has 2 columns ( or 3 ). each row has a user_id and a unique token that you generate and store when the user submits the "I forgot my password" form. now the route that takes care of the reset process will be on this form `password/reset/{user_id}/{token}`.

when the user access to that URL, you must verify that the token is linked to the user_id, and when the user submits the reset password form, you must delete that row on your password_reset table.